# CakePHP - SQL: joining tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

I have 4 tables:

```
stores {id, name, owner_id, city_id, ...}
store_managers {id, store_id, user_id, ...}   // since I'm not associating (i have my reasons) the table to the others by cake's association, the name is not by the cakePHP naming conventions. 
cities {id, name, ...}
users {id, name, ...}
```

Now.. in the `stores_controller` there is a function called 'stores_stats()' that collects some statistics about the stores owned by the user and shows it. The owner_id is coming from the `$this->Auth->user('id')`
I want to use a `$this->Store->find('all')` call to get the following information:

1. The store record itself.
2. The store managers of each store.
3. City record for each store.
4. The store record itself.

The `users` and the `cities` tables are associated with the `stores` table and a `find('all')` query returns the data correctly about them. my problem is with `store_managers` table.

How can I join the `store_managers` to the query?
And, just to get it right - how do I write such query myself?
The following query gives me something.. else..

```
SELECT *
FROM stores
LEFT JOIN cities ON stores.id = cities.id
LEFT JOIN store_managers ON store_managers.store_id = stores.id
WHERE stores.id = 122 AND stores.owner_id = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use CakePHP's containable behavior. ([read more about it here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html?highlight=containable#ContainableBehavior)).

```
//Store Model
class Store extends AppModel {

var $actsAs = array('Containable');

//associations
//validation

//the method you call from the controller
function getStoreStats() {
    $this->recursive = -1;
    $params = array();
    $params['containable'] = array(
        'User' => array(
             'StoreManager',
        ),
        'City'
    );
    $data = $this->find('all', $params);
    return $data;
}
}
```

The idea is, you set recursive to `-1`, which limits the data you get back from the Store to itself.  Then, using containable, you specify what other related data you want returned.

Make sure if you're reading the CakePHP book to verify you're on the right version (1.3, 2.0...etc).

Also, it's quite common to just set `$this->recursive=-1;` in the app model do it's the default for all.

Assuming all your relationships are set up correctly, and none of them are HABTM relationship, Containable should work great for you.

Comment: thanks, i agree. but i still need the join and simple sql way.. can you please help?

Comment: You're trying to use Cake's JOIN?  Or just get it to work with regular SQL?

Comment: Both - tho regular sql will be enough

Comment: Probably best to just start a new question with just "Here's my tables and here's the data I want to get - how would I do this with MySQL?" This question sounded as if you wanted the data by using Cake, not the raw MySQL way (especially since there is no mysql tag on the question)

Comment: 1) you are correct, i will add the mysql tag. 2) it seems like i wrote the sql just fine, but my problem is that i get only one record from the store_managers for each store.. i will follow your first advice as well.
thanks

Comment: That's all you can get unless you use GROUP_CONCAT, which allows you to get back more than one item within a cell:  [group_concat details here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

The CakePHP solution to this would be implementing relation to the stores model. If there are many store managers, you can put this code into the Stores model:

```
$hasMany = array(
'StoreManagers' => array( 'className' => 'StoreManagers')
);
```

Or if there is only one store manager:

```
$hasOne = 'StoreManagers';
```

If you stick to the naming conventions, the find() call shall return array, where for each Store shoud be 'StoreManagers' item (or array), where all linked items would be fetched.

For more on the subject of joining tables see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Comment: Thanks, but as i wrote - I don't want to associate the models. i want to add a join for that matter